# Is there a way to bookmark questions on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, questions, stackexchange, bookmarks

There must be a way to 'follow' a question or even a user through SE (i.e., it's easy to do it with browser bookmarks).

Answer (score 4):

Click the Star under the vote count for any question to mark it as a Favorite.

[image: Favorite]

See also: [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/21960)

Alternatively, every question has an RSS feed. The link is in the lower right corner after any answers. Just add that to your favorite [feed-reader](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feed-reader).

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to follow a user?

Comment: Beyond the RSS feed that is available on a user profile, no. Stack Exchange very specifically lacks social network features because it's not a social network. See also: [A “friends list” on Stack Overflow would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/886/21960)

Comment: Okay, it would be nice to follow users who contribute productive answers, not necessarily to 'connect' with them.

Comment: You could always make a feature request at [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com), but I would expect it to not get a very good reception. Besides, as I've mentioned, there is an RSS feed already.